# Hazard ratio for more than two groups

Tags: cox-model, hazard, proportional-hazards

Consider the line of code below for implementing Cox model in R and finding the hazard ratio:

```
 fitcox <- coxph(Surv(Survival,Death) ~ clusters, data = data)
```

Here "clusters" is a vector with 30 values as 1, 30 values as 2 ,30 values a 3 and 30 values as 4. The Kaplan-Meier  graph consists of 4 plots ; one for each cluster. When I run the above command, the hazard ratio comes out to be  1.3154 (i.e. exp(coef) in R).  What does that mean?  I mean I have 4 groups but hazard ratio is supposed to be between 2 groups only. What does R mean by 1.3154?

Further Information:

```
head(data)

Survival Death clusters

" 345"   "0"   "1" 

"  85"   "0"   "1"

"1058"   "0"   "1" 

" 964"   "1"   "1" 

"1315"   "0"   "2" 

" 669"   "0"   "2"

 summary(fitcox)
```

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/96DMh.png

Comment: Can you plot the raw output and a sample of the data?  Something like the output of `head(data)`

Comment: Please consider it now.

Comment: Yea. This is what I was looking for. Thanks
with  $as.factor$ it is giving me 3 hazard ratios for clusters1, cluster2, cluster3. Does it mean that cluster1 is the reference?

Comment: Since this is what it was i post it as the answer..

Comment: With  $as.factor$ it is giving me 3 hazard ratios for clusters1, cluster2, cluster3. Does it mean that cluster1 is the reference?

And what about hazard ratio between cluster2 & cluster3  and cluster3 & cluster4 and clustrer4 & cluster2.

Comment: But all there are 6 hazard ratios among 4 groups. It shows only 3.

Comment: Yes, this is normal behavior. You can read about dummy coding, here for example https://www.statisticssolutions.com/dummy-coding-the-how-and-why/

Comment: Does this mean that if I am given a hazard ratio(HR) as $HRa =hazard(cluster2)/hazard(cluster1)$ and another hazard ratio as $HRb=hazard(cluster3)/hazard(cluster1)$ then the hazard ratio between cluster2 and cluster3  is given by $HRc=HRa/HRb$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your predictor has the class "numeric" and thus R thinks it is one continuous variable and determines the hazard ratio for this one variable. If this is the case all you need to do is

```
data$clusters <- as.factor(data$clusters)
```

After that R will provide three hazard ratios, each showing the hazard ratio of a given group versus the reference. You can change the refernce group with.

```
data$clusters <- relevel(data$clusters, "name_of_group")
```