# Obtain hazard ratio from other hazard ratios

Tags: hazard, proportional-hazards

Given a hazard ratio($HR$) as $$_{b}=ℎ(b)/ℎ(a)$$ and another hazard ratio as $$_{c}=ℎ(c)/ℎ(a)$$ How can we obtain the hazard  ratio between $b$ and $c$  from $HR_{b}$ and $HR_{c}$ ?

Here $hazard(a),hazard(b),hazard(c)$ are hazards for three subgroups consisting of  samples of a bigger data-set on which cluster analysis was applied to find the 3 subgroups(of samples). The model was decribed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401341/hazard-ratio-for-more-than-two-groups/401416#401416) before

Comment: Write out the full models (you're probably conditioning on something, e.g. covariates) and sample characteristics/study design, e.g., are HRb and HRc estimated using the same dataset so that a single protocol is in place?

Comment: Done. Please check it now.

Comment: If my answer(s) clarify your questions consider marking them as answered.

Comment: Yea. Yours answers helped. I will mark them answered soon on the basis of your answers...just waiting  a bit if someone else has something to add.

Comment: Using cluster analysis to find groups to test is almost always problematic.  You either need to use the continuous distance from cluster centers for each observations, or directly analyze the measurements that went into the clustering and drop the clustering.

Comment: @FrankHarrell thanks for the insightful  comment: Could you please elaborate on why  cluster analysis  to find groups to test is almost always problematic. I have clustered genetic data consisting of 100 samples and 20000 genes into 3  groups of roughly 33 samples each and proved that the clustering is statistically significant. From your comment it seems that this is not the right way. Could you please elaborate or provide some reference. This is important for me.

Comment: You have also suggested "using continuous distance from cluster centers for each observation" ; are you talking about the cluster centers obtained from some analysis done beforehand e.g. in my case, cluster analysis(to find the clusters and so their centers). If that is not the case then how do we find the cluster centers. Please elaborate or provide some reference. Thanks again.

Comment: I wasn't clear on whether you were clustering observations or clustering variables.  It seems you are clustering observations, which is the more problematic situation.  Clustering, at least the kind I'm familiar with, groups observations but within each cluster there is too much heterogeneity of the observations to consider them as a homogeneous group as you are doing.  Continuous distances or non-clustering methods will fix this.  (Imagine 2 clusters as touching circles; a subject at the edge of one may be more like obs. in the other cluster than in her own cluster.)

Comment: @FrankHarrell : It is insights like this that make this website worth using. Thanks again. If I may request more of your time, could you please direct me towards some study material where I can read more about  continuous distances and non-clustering methods.

Comment: I don't have a reference at my fingertips for the distance from cluster center, but it is motivated by the need to take into account heterogeneity within clusters, i.e., clusters don't have a radius of zero.  For non-cluster methods see my [RMS book and course notes](http://fharrell.com/links).

Comment: @FrankHarrell How can I check the heterogeneity of my clustered data. I mean, is there some standard procedure. Right now I am using Silhouettes in R. Is that a good way to see the heterogeneity??

Comment: Very easy.  If you have only one variable and it is discrete, you have homogeneity within each category of that categorical variable.  If you have a continuous variable that has a non-flat relationship with the outcome, you do not have homogeneity and don't need to test for it to find out.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I revisited this thread  and  realized  I haven't  understood  your point. Could you please answer the following again in the simplest terms with examples: 1). Why using cluster analysis to find groups to test is almost always problematic? 2). You said, "You either need to use the continuous distance from cluster centers for each observations, or directly analyze the measurements that went into the clustering and drop the clustering." Please elaborate this(maybe with an example). 3). How is  gene expression data heterogeneous. All the values are numbers  like 0.00322 ?

 Thanks

Comment: Cluster analysis on one continuous variable = marginal binning, i.e., creation of (hopefully short) intervals.  This is a mistake.  Instead use position along the axis continuously.  Now extend this to multiple dimensions.  If you use clusters to bin you are ignored tremendous within-cluster heterogeneity, and in some cases an observation at the edge of a cluster is closer to an observation in another cluster than to observations in its "own" cluster.  If you must cluster, using distance measures and not binning greatly improves the situation.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks again. In fact, the clusters in my methodology are allowed to overlap and so some observations may belong to more than one cluster. I think that addresses(to some extend) one of the points you guided me to. The second point, i.e. within cluster heterogeneity, I don't know how to approach this problem. When I plot Silhouettes in R , it shows that the observations in the clusters are not similar to their own clusters.

Comment: Allowing for membership in multiple clusters definitely helps but doesn't go as far as using multiple distance metrics.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks again. This discussion is has been quite useful to me. 

However, I am still struggling with the idea of 'within cluster heterogeneity' and how to minimize it, if at all it needs to be minimized....(The data I am using is gene expression data for lung, colon, kidney, liver cancers)

Comment: The heterogeneity is just a consequence of using clusters as a data reduction tool.  Since clusters don't have a radius of 0.0 this heterogeneity can be dealt with by using distance from cluster centers rather than binary cluster membership.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks again. I think I got the  basic idea. To summarize with an example; The data I am dealing with is unlike clustering males and females where we can have a binary classification. It is more like a continuous valued clustering where we can't classify with 100% confidence. Like the case when we are trying to sub-type cancer from gene expression data. It can never be a clear classification and patient can have traits of all the newly discovered sub-types leading to "with in cluster heterogeneity'  and no defined inter-cluster decision boundaries. Is this example correct?

Comment: Yes - a key point is what you said about clustering on continuous variables.  And note that empirical statistical clustering does not define cancer subtypes in a defensible biological way.  See [here](https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/phenotyping-clinical-syndromes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with HR(c)/HR(b)

The great thing about R is that you can try it if you are not sure. Like this here:

```
# firstly, load some data
data(lung)

# creating some factor
# number of each cluster (I use 3 clusters)
nk <- nrow(lung)/3
# create some factor
lung$cluster <- factor(c(rep("cluster1", nk), rep("cluster2", 
nk), rep("cluster3", nk)))

# fit models
# Here reference level is cluster1
m1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ cluster, data=lung)

# with cluster 2 as reference
# change reference level to cluster2
lung$cluster <- relevel(lung$cluster, "cluster2")
# fit a model with cluster2 as reference
m2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ cluster, data=lung)

# calculating hazard ratio for cluater2 vs. cluster3 from m1
exp(m1$coefficients["clustercluster3"]) / 
  exp(m1$coefficients["clustercluster2"])
0.8416011

# comparing it to the hazard ratio cluster2 vs. cluster3. from model fit
exp(m2$coefficients["clustercluster3"])
0.8416011
```